# Batch script returning unwanted file list results

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a folder and many subfolders containing videos. One subfolder is named Screenshots and has a folder structure that mirrors the video subfolders. Each video has one jpg screenshot: filename.ext.jpg. Some of those jpg files are no longer needed as the corresponding videos have been deleted.

> ```
> d:\folder1
>    - video1.mp4
>    - video2.mkv
> d:\folder2
> d:\folder3
> d:\screenshots\folder1
>    - video1.mp4.jpg
>    - video2.mkv.jpg
> d:\screenshots\folder2
> d:\screenshots\folder3
> ```

I created this to find and delete the outdated jpg's. It saves a list of screenshots with full paths, minus the .jpg, then removes the screenshot folder from the path resulting in a list of paths to the video files.

It is then supposed to return a list of all video files that no longer exist It does that, but also lists many files that are still present.

Looking for a way to fix this, or a smarter way to do the task.

Thank you.

```
set screenshotlist="%temp%\screenshot_work\screenshots.txt"
set folder=D:\screenshots

mkdir %temp%\screenshot_work

:: get list of screenshots without .jpg extension
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir %folder% /s /a-d /b') do echo %%~dpnf >>%screenshotlist%

:: edit screenshots.txt, remove "screenshots\"
call jrepl "screenshots\\" "" /f %screenshotlist% /i /o -

:: check if files exist in D:\
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%f in (%screenshotlist%) do (if not exist %%f echo %%f needs to be deleted)

rd /s /q %temp%\screenshot_work
pause
```

Comment: So there is a single screenshot file per video, right? What about this: `for %%I in ("D:\root\screenshots\*.*.jpg") do set "FLAG=" & (for /D %%J in ("D:\root\*") do if exist "%%~J\%%~nI" set "FLAG=#") & if not defined FLAG ECHO del "%%~J"`?

Comment: I've edited the question. One screenshot per video, but the videos are in subfolders and the screenshots are in subfolders that mirror the folder structure of the videos.

Comment: Alright, so if the screenshots are placed in sub-directories, I need to adapt my suggestion: `for /R "D:\root\screenshots" %%I in ("*.*.jpg") do set "FLAG=" & (for /D %%J in ("D:\root\*") do if /I not "%%~nxI"=="screenshots" if exist "%%~J\%%~nI" set "FLAG=#") & if not defined FLAG ECHO del "%%~J"`?

Comment: @aschipfl I had to remove \root, and the script runs but I get this as output: del "%~J"?

Comment: Yes, just to show you for verification what would become deleted if you removed the upper-case `ECHO` command…

Comment: @aschipfl what I mean is that it outputs `del "%~J" ?` over and over instead of the files.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not realize that it should read `del "%%~I"`…

Comment: It lists files now, but it's listing every file in D:\screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have understood your question was that you would like to delete the ".jpg" files within the Screenshots directory that do not have a corresponding video file in the Video directory. A corresponding video file would be the name of the screenshot without the ".jpg" extension.

1. Open PowerShell ISE
2. Paste the code into the script pane
3. Modify $Video_Directory and $Screenshot_Directory
4. Press Play

```
$Video_Directory = "C:\temp4\Video"
$Screenshot_Directory = "C:\temp4\Screenshot"

$Date = Get-Date -UFormat "%d %b %Y %H%M%S"

$Transcript_Directory = "C:\POSH_Transcripts"
$Transcript = "$Transcript_Directory\Transcript_$($Date)"
New-Item -ItemType "Directory" -Path $Transcript_Directory

Start-Transcript -Path $Transcript -Append
Get-ChildItem -Path $Screenshot_Directory -File -Recurse -Include "*.jpg" | ForEach-Object {
    $Video = $_.Name.Replace(".jpg", "")
    If (Test-Path "$Video_Directory\$Video"){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "The video ($($_.Name.Replace(`".jpg`", `"`"))) for the screenshot ($($_.Name)) exists."
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "The video for screenshot $($_.Name) does not exist. Removing screenshot."
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Verbose
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$($_.Name) has been removed"
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
Start-Process notepad.exe $Transcript
```

Comment: Ran it and it deleted all the screenshots. I'm creating all the screenshots from scratch, so I don't need a script anymore. LOL. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I don't understand powershell, but I'm guessing it's because my folders are `$Video_Directory = "D:\"` and `$Screenshot_Directory = "D:\Screenshots"`

Comment: Hello, I tested my script before I sent it and it worked successfully. I'm sorry it didn't work for you but my scripts are use-at-your-own-risk as all scripts are when they are received from an unpaid stranger over the internet. I would recommend trying to recover your deleted files from your recycle bin, they were screenshots so it is unlikely that the files were permanently deleted. If they were permanently deleted there is freeware to recover items that have been permanently deleted because what permanently deleted means is they were removed from index. I'll retry the script with the (1/2)

Comment: directory names that you provided after work and fix any issues. Additionally, the script should have ran verbose can you provide a transcript? Additionally, there is a parameter for many PowerShell cmdlets called "-whatif" which will tell you what it will try to do without actually doing it. (2/2)

Comment: Sorry if I came across as accusatory or ungrateful. The files were not put into the recycle bin, it was an external drive without one. I considered recovery, but since I wanted extra files removed, I found it easier to just redo them all this time. However, I will need to do this again in the future, so I am interested in getting this to work. The -whatif is extremely useful, and will make it so much nicer for me to experiment with the script and Powershell in general.

Comment: I believe I found the problem. The screenshots part of the script is recursive, but this part doesn't appear to be: `If (Test-Path "$Video_Directory\$Video"){` Since all my video files are in subfolders, it's not seeing them.